# SQL execution time took more time when database is in the different server

Tags: sql-server

SQL execution time took more time to complete when database is in the different server compare if the web and database are on the same server

if the database and web server are in one server only: Execution time is 3mins

if the database and web server are in different servers: Execution time is 12mins

What are the things to check?

Comment: You appear to make an observation or two here, but fail to *ask a question*.

Comment: this is also not a best practice to keep iis and database servers in same box,you will need to check wait type and post execution plans of both queries

Comment: but the queries are just the same, I know also the standard that the iis and database should be in the separate server, but i'm surprise that in the ideal setup i got a bad performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many factors that delay or slowdown the SQL execution, Size of data, network bandwidth, poor execution plan etc are few of them, You can start looking around with these factors and narrow down your analysis. I would suggest to start from comparing execution plan from both servers.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both the server IIS and DB Server having same specification, same data size then there are likely chances that your DB server configuration is different from what you have on IIS, Check for memory and CPU settings. Do you see same execution plan ?